# How to sort a dataframe in decreasing order lapply and sort in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Not sure if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find anything that either solves my original problem or the issue I'm running into with the partial I did find.

The goal is to sort a dataframe independently by column.

Reproducible example

```
a <- data.frame(name = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),date1 = c(2,3,1,3,1,2),date2 = c(0,2,3,1,2,0),date3 = c(0,2,0,3,2,1))
a
  name date1 date2 date3
1    a     2     0     0
2    a     3     2     2
3    a     1     3     0
4    b     3     1     3
5    b     1     2     2
6    b     2     0     1

b <- ddply(a, "name", function(x) { as.data.frame(lapply(x, sort))
b
  name date1 date2 date3
1    a     1     0     0
2    a     2     2     0
3    a     3     3     2
4    b     1     0     1
5    b     2     1     2
6    b     3     2     3
```

Now this works as expected, but is the opposite of what I'm looking to do. 
Desired output

```
b
  name date1 date2 date3
1    a     3     3     2
2    a     2     2     0
3    a     1     0     0
4    b     3     2     3
5    b     2     1     2
6    b     1     0     1
```

I've tried to add in the `decreasing=T` parameter but haven't had any luck with the variations I've tried and usually end up with an error about missing arguments or undefined columns being selected. How does one correctly implement a decreasing sort with this syntax and/or otherwise achieve the end result without relying on explicitly naming the columns (they names are dates so change often)

**Bonus**
How could this code be adapted to account for NA's with `na.last`

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried using `order` instead of `sort`, you can then set decreasing = FALSE/TRUE

Comment: I want to make sure I understand the goal - you want the data sorted by the `name` column, and then *within each unique `name` group*, you want to sort each of the `date` columns independently, i.e., not preserving rows. Is that right?

Comment: @GregorThomas thats correct. I realize that this invalidates all the original rows but based on the data and eventual output it's not the end of the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you nuked the data.frame rows with your code, not a very good practice standard dplyr use the arrange() function like this

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- data.frame(name = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),date1 = c(2,3,1,3,1,2),date2 = c(0,2,3,1,2,0),date3 = c(0,2,0,3,2,1))

a %>% 
  arrange(name,-date1)
```

If you want to live a dangerous life here is the code for it

```
a %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate_all(sort,decreasing  = TRUE)

  name  date1 date2 date3
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         3     3     2
2 a         2     2     0
3 a         1     0     0
4 b         3     2     3
5 b         2     1     2
6 b         1     0     1
```

Comment: This does nuke code but the way My data is formatted it is a necessary evil for the output. For any other beginners that see this you are able to use na.last as an input parameter in the mutate_all function to handle incomplete data.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with the `data.table` package is the following

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(name = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),date1 = c(2,3,1,3,1,2),date2 = c(0,2,3,1,2,0),date3 = c(0,2,0,3,2,1))

# alternatively:
# a <- data.frame(name = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),date1 = c(2,3,1,3,1,2),date2 = c(0,2,3,1,2,0),date3 = c(0,2,0,3,2,1))
# setDT(a)

b <- a[, lapply(.SD, sort, decreasing = TRUE), by = name]
```

`.SD` returns the subset of data, in this case created with the `by = name`. It splits the original `data.table` by the values in the given column.

This also fulfills your bonus requirement, the `na.last` can be supplied.

```
aa <- data.table(name = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),date1 = c(NA,3,1,3,1,NA),date2 = c(0,2,NA,1,2,0),date3 = c(0,2,0,3,2,NA))
bb <- aa[, lapply(.SD, sort, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = TRUE), by = name]
```